# Soft foods that are high in vitamin B3

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients

I recently found out that having sufficient vitamin B3 can help prevent gingivitis, I need to know some good soft foods that have a lot of vitamin B3 because eating hard food right now will likely crack more of my teeth. I want to achieve the recommended daily intake.

Answer (score 2):

A list of foods rich in vitamin B3 (niacin) is available [here](http://www.dietitians.ca/Your-Health/Nutrition-A-Z/Vitamins/Food-Sources-of-Niacin.aspx). Although meats are the richest source, those are often not soft to chew. However, if you look at that table you'll see that it shouldn't be difficult to consume the RDA even on a vegetarian diet.